# Subquery returning dupes in LOJ

Tags: sql-server

Perhaps a simple solution, but for some reason this is tripping me up.  Need to do a left outer join and the join condition is the transaction_id and the decision_id.  The decision_id has to select the decision_id where the accept_ind = 'Y' or if there is none, then select decision_id = 1 which is guaranteed to exist.

--Decision table
transaction_id(pk)  decision)id(pk)   accepted_ind
A                    1                NULL
A                    2                
A                    4                Y
B                    1                
B                    2                Y
C                    1                Y
D                    1                N
D                    2                O
D                    3                Y

```
  DECLARE decision TABLE (
  transaction_id NCHAR(1),      
  decision_id INT,      
  accepted_ind NCHAR(1) NULL
  )  

  INSERT decision VALUES     
  ( 'A' , 1 , NULL ),     
  ( 'A' , 2 , '' ),     
  ( 'A' , 4 , 'Y' ),     
  ( 'B' , 1 , '' ),     
  ( 'B' , 2 , 'N' ),  
  ( 'C' , 1 , 'Y' ),     
  ( 'D' , 1 , 'N' ),     
  ( 'D' , 2 , 'O' ),     
  ( 'D' , 3 , 'Y' ) 


  DECLARE load TABLE (
  transaction_id NCHAR(1),      
  consignee CHAR(240),
  miles INT
  )

  INSERT load VALUES     
  ( 'A' , 'COSTCO' , 32 ),     
  ( 'B' , 'SAMS CLUB' , 43 ),     
  ( 'C' , 'WG&R' ,  62),     
  ( 'D' , 'SAMS CLUB' , 15 )
```

The LOJ is taking a load table and joining the decsion table to return only one row.  I think I need a second set of eyes.  This is what I am currently trying to get to work is simple:

```
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   L_DECISION with (nolock)      
  on L_LOAN.transaction_id = L_DECISION.transaction_id and 
  L_DECISION.decision_id = (select decision_id 
          from L_DECISION d2 with (nolock)
          where cust_accept_ind = 'Y' OR 
        (NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM l_decision d3 with (nolock)
         where cust_accept_ind = 'Y' and 
         d3.transaction_id = d2.transaction_id) and
         decision_id = 1) )
```

I however am returning dupes in the subquery.  I have played with the subquery and written an external query to try to find the issue with no luck.  Any assistance is appreciated as I return to working with SQL after many years of not touching it much.

Chris

Comment: [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the subquery conditions are not correct, try changing the LOJ to this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN   L_DECISION with (nolock)
     on L_LOAN.transaction_id = L_DECISION.transaction_id and 
L_DECISION.decision_id = case when 
                         (select count(*)
                            from L_DECISION d2 (nolock)
                           where cust_accept_ind = 'Y'
                          and d2.transaction_id = L_DECISION.transaction_id) = 0
             then 1 else (select top 1 d3.decision_id 
                            from L_DECISION d3 (nolock) 
                           where cust_accept_ind = 'Y'
                             and d3.transaction_id = L_DECISION.transaction_id) end
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for your assitance, this does exactly what I needed it to do and I also learned from this a new technique!